# restcomm conference waiturl doesn't work

Tags: restcomm

I have the latest Docker instance of Restcomm. I tried to play with Conference demo. I tried dialing in a number using Olympus sample code and mapped the number to sample XML provided with Restcomm 'dial-conference.xml'. I can hear the initial announcemnt, but the waitUrl music isn't played. I tried RVD also to use the wait music, I even tried replacing the wav file with 'say' command, but it didn't work.
Can someone explain why it is happening? Is it an Olympus issue or an issue with RCML Conference.

Comment: Hi Nitesh. Does the same issue happen when you call with a regular SIP client (non webrtc/Olympus) ?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. There is another problem ref that: For some reason, Restcomm doesn't like the SIP call coming from Voxbone network. It allows me to make only one call from Voxbone DID and for some reason, it always keeps the call status 'In progress'? Any further call attempts are rejected with 503. And  I have to restart Restcomm